# Fade out all the "LI" elements

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

Please tell me how to use PrototypeJS to hide (fade out) all the `li` elements.

P.S. there can be any number of `li` elements.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="rtr-img" >
  <ul id="rotator_ul">
    <li id="rtr-img-1"><a href="/link/1/"><img src="b1.jpg"/></a></li>
    <li id="rtr-img-2"><a href="/link/2/"><img src="b2.jpg"/></a></li>
    <li id="rtr-img-3"><a href="/link/3/"><img src="b3.jpg"/></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can `rotator_ul`/`rtr-img` be faded out instead of all `<li>` elements? If so, that would make it easier.

Comment: @shaquin-trifonoff No, I need it again after the show one of LI. Thank u )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, PrototypeJS does not have animations/effects built in. You can use the Scriptaculous library, which is an add-on to Prototype, and provides a [`fade` method](http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/effect-fade/).

If you want to fade out the entire `ul` element:

```
$("rotator_ul").fade({ 
    from: 1,
    to: 0 
});
```

If you want to (as stated in your question) fade out all `li` elements:

```
$$("li").invoke("fade", { 
    from: 1, 
    to: 0 
});
```

Comment: Thank, you. Everything turned out. And if you do not know how to make the action after the lapse of extinction?

Comment: @frops - No problem, glad I could help. You can pass a callback function to `fade` by setting the `afterFinish` property in the options object. That function will be executed once the fade animation has finished.

Comment: I was going to suggest modifying `opacity` style of the elements with JavaScript, but this library already does it!